# Hibernate HQL or Criteria alternative for Filters to Filter on Collection (One to Many) object fileds

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, hql

[CHANGED TITLE]

I am working with Parent Child relationships and we need to filter on Child entity's fields. And also there are some Collections defined at Parent and Child which are EAGER fetch.

When tried with HQL Result is wrong with more Child Objects built than what I am expecting.

My Object Relationship:

```
Cat -> Kitten  (One to Many)
Kitten -> Owner (One to One)
Kitten -> Vet_Doctor (One to One)
```

Data:

```
Cat1
  -> KittenA - Male
  -> KittenB - Male
  -> KittenC - Female
```

And Oweners, doctors etc.,

HQL:

```
select distinct cats from Cat as cats
    inner join cats.kitten as kittens
    left outer join kittens.owner
    left outer join kittens.doctor
where kittens.gender = :gender
```

When I search for 'male' , results getting both including male, female kittens, which is wrong.

Queries from log (something like this):

```
select distinct cats.id, cats.name, cats.age 
from Cat as cats
        inner join cats.Kitten on Kitten.catid = Cat.id
        left outer join Owner on Kitten.ownerid = Owner.id
        left outer join Vet_Doctor on Kitten.doctorid = Vet_Doctor.id
 where Kitten.gender = 'male';


select Kitten.id, Kitten.name, Owner.name, Vet_Doctor.name 
from Cat
        inner join Kitten on Kitten.catid = Cat.id
        left outer join Owner on Kitten.ownerid = Owner.id
        left outer join Vet_Doctor on Kitten.doctorid = Vet_Doctor.id
 where Cat.id = 1;
```

I find out can use Hibernate Filters to filter Child Objects. But how to do it with HQL or Criteria?

Anyone can please help, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try to rewrite a query in this way (it is a template of course)

```
select distinct Cat 
  from Cat cat inner join cat.kitten kitten
  where kitten.gender = :gender
```

**Updated**

In your HQL query you don't need joins on kittens.owner and kittens.doctor because of you don't use it in the where clause. Just use this

```
select distinct cats from Cat as cats
    inner join cats.kitten as kittens
where kittens.gender = :gender
```

Comment: thank you, I tried as you mentioned, but still results are same. while checking to solve this I found there is way to filter on Collections (child entity) using Filters in hibernate. 

But I am looking how to do it in HQL or using Criteria.

Comment: @skstar Please, add your persistent classes to your question to check out your mappings.

Comment: edited my question, based on my finding that it normal behavior when hibernate build Objects only filter on what was returning, in my case it is list of Parent objects (Cat). To filter Child objects need to use Filters. But I am looking how to achieve this using HQL or Criteria.